# Is there a more C similar way to print 2D arrays in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am currently learning java, When I came to the "Multidimensional Array" lessons I was a little confused. I was wondering why the nested loop has at its termination `counterVar < 2dArrayName[row].length`. Why do wee need the Parameter [row] next to the 2DArray?

Sample code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Program {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String [][] arr = new String [2][2];

        for(int row = 0; row < arr.length;row++) {
            for(int column = 0; column < arr[row].length; column++) {
                arr[row][column] = sc.nextLine();
             }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Because not all nested arrays need to be the same size (they just happen to be in your case)

Comment: A "2D" array is a confusing terminology. There are no such things as two dimensional or three dimensional data structures in Java. A "2D" array is nothing else than an array of arrays. This means you could have one array of length 5 stored in there, one of length 10, and so on. That's why you need to get the specific length of the array you are currently looking at with `arr[row]`.

Comment: Because of jagged arrays.

Comment: So, in my case I could also use only (in the nested for loop) colummn <arr.length? As I have a [2][2] array? So we need the collumn<arr[row].length termination If we would have something like this [2][4] ? So like I have explained here @Ben ?

Comment: You could in theory do that as your "inner" arrays are of the same length compared to your outer array. I would highly recommend not to though as changing the size of your array at any point would cause confusion and errors.

Comment: I don't get it what you are trying to tell me. Could you repeat it (for a noob)? @Ben

Comment: You have an array of arrays. So you have an (outer) array containing several (inner) arrays. Like `new String[outerLength][innerLength]`. If the length of the outer array equals the length of the inner array you are fine with just using `outerLength`, but should you now change either the outer or the inner length you will run into problems.

Comment: In other words: Don't use outer.length for the inner arrays. While it might work here it's a bad habit to get into. Just start using outer[inner].length directly.

Comment: Could you write a sample code to make me understand better as I don't get it right now....

Comment: @Alan You COULD also say `row < 2` and `column < 2`, but then you would need to be careful if you change the code to use a different array size.

Comment: Just remember: 2d arrays do not exist in Java. They're just arrays of arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Java this is valid:

```
String[][] demo = { {"test1","test2","test3"}, {"test4","test5"}, {"test6"}};
```

Having such construct you can successfully execute

```
System.out.println(demo[0][2]);
```

but

```
System.out.println(demo[1][2]);
```

will cause an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`, since the second row has only 2 entries instead of 3 like the first row.

Comment: And that's why we have to use arr[row].length ? Because Row 2 has only 2 Elements? And row one has 3 so we have to get theccolummn length of each specifc row?

Comment: @Alan Yes, exactly.

Answer (score 1):

`Arrays.toString()` is something loosely related to your question (printing content of arrays in Java), so it should also be known.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html

Examples (from https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/arrays-tostring-in-java-with-examples/)

```
[true, true, false, true]
[10, 20, 30]
[g, e, e, k, s]
[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Guess you have an array of type int: `int arr[][] = new int[2][3];`

in this case, 2 indicates the number of arrays, 3 indicates the counts of each those arrays elements.

On your code, `arr.length` is the count of arrays (in your case it is first 2), but `arr[row].length` indicates counts of `arr[row]`'s arrays elements(in your case it is second 2).

Comment: So, wee need arr[row] length to get the amount of stored variables in that specific row? So i.e. arr[row 0] has 3 stored variables?

Comment: {{"Test","Test","Test"},{"Test2","Test2","Test2"}}